# Three.,js basic material wireframe;true works or not with planebuffergeometry

Tags: three.js

I have used it and it seems the horizontal edges are not drawed...
[image]

I have seen some posts and I'm not sure whether this material can be used or the wireframehelper has to be applied instead. 
TH.

Comment: Yep, you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5616)

Comment: yes I already saw it...